# Assembly language to C

Tags: c, assembly, bit-shift

So I have the following assembly language code which I need to convert into C. I am confused on a few lines of the code.

I understand that this is a `for` loop. I have added my comments on each line.

I think the `for` loop goes like this

```
for (int i = 1; i > 0; i << what?) {
    //Calculate result
}
```

What is the test condition? And how do I change it?

Looking at the assembly code, what does the variable 'n' do?

This is Intel x86 so the format is movl = source, dest

```
  movl 8(%ebp), %esi     //Get x
  movl 12(%ebp), %ebx    //Get n
  movl $-1, %edi         //This should be result
  movl $1, %edx          //The i of the loop
.L2:
  movl %edx, %eax
  andl %esi, %eax
  xorl %eax, %edi        //result = result ^ (i & x)
  movl %ebx, %ecx        //Why do we do this? As we never use $%ebx or %ecx again
  sall %cl, %edx         //Where did %cl come from?
  testl %edx, %edx       //Tests if i != what? - condition of the for loop
  jne .L2                //Loop again
  movl %edi, %eax        //Otherwise return result.
```

Comment: testl %edx, %edx checks if edx is 0. and then jne - jump if not zero.

Comment: Which lines are you confused? In C, a for loop is for(;;) {}

Comment: Why are you converting legacy asm into C?

Comment: @Abyx Why translate to intel syntax?

Comment: @mathepic to make it readable

Comment: @Abyx But its not unreadable, everything is essentially the same except the ordering...

Comment: The [Boomerang Decompiler](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/cando.php?hidemenu) is able to convert assembly language to C, so it may be useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sall %cl, %edx` shifts %edx left by `%cl` bits.  (`%cl`, for reference, is the low byte of `%ecx`.)  The subsequent `testl` tests whether that shift zeroed out %edx.

The `jne` is called that because it's often used in the context of comparisons, which in ASM are often just subtractions.  The flags would be set based on the difference; ZF would be set if the items are equal (since x - x == 0).  It's also called `jnz` in Intel syntax; i'm not sure whether GNU allows that too.

All together, the three instructions translate to `i <<= n; if (i != 0) goto L2;`.  That plus the label seem to make a for loop.

```
for (i = 1; i != 0; i <<= n) { result ^= i & x; }
```

Or, more correctly (but achieving the same goal), a do...while loop.

```
i = 1;
do { result ^= i & x; i <<= n; } while (i != 0);
```